# What Editor has NO Syntax Highlighting and can copy&paste text in GTK interfaces?

Tags: clipboard, gtk3, text-editor

Simple problem: I have a JSON file that is used for snapshot serialization of a JS-based VM.

It contains a shitload of data and every single editor crashes while trying to open it, except vim.
But, vim, of course - can't right click and copy the whole file into the clipboard.

When trying out vim-gtk, vim-nox, vim-gnome etc., they don't offer a proper GTK GUI for Gnome3. They all missed updating the library to GTK3, so I have no menu, no mouse, no context menus etc. there.

So I can't open the file with any GTK based editor (mousepad, leafpad, geany, gedit, etc. - all will crash, trust me). I tried out every single editor that was mentioned on Google Fu lists, forum posts etc. Really, all will crash because you can't simply deactivate syntax highlighting.

I simply want the text content of the whole file in the clipboard, so I can paste it into the Web Browser of my choice.

How to achieve that?

PS: No, I won't install whole KDE for a simple clipboard task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`pastebinit`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit), you'll get a link to open the json file in your browser:

```
sudo apt-get install pastebinit
cat data.json | pastebinit -b http://paste.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint! Worked for me like a charm.

Comment: @user3400700 It's also possible to use Vim: [Copy all the lines to clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620018/copy-all-the-lines-to-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extension of the file, I assume that it is "json". Therefore no syntax highlighting should be applied.

```
$ cp your_file.json your_file
$ gedit your_file
```

Comment: Where can the extensions for gedit, for example, be found?

Comment: `cp your_file.json your_file` and then `gedit your_file`

Answer (score 0):

[emelFM2](http://emelfm2.net/) is a file manager that comes with an internal GTK-based text viewer and editor (bound to `F3` and `F4`). It has no syntax highlighting. To install use the [emelFM2 PPA (release)](https://launchpad.net/~emelfm2/+archive/ubuntu/release).